# Within a loop, what's the difference between calling a function that yields vs storing it in a variable?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

For example, if I have:

```
def yield_range(x):
  for i in range(x):
    yield i

for x in yield_range(10):
  print(x)

yr_result = yield_range(10)
for x in yr_result:
  print(x)
```

I understand that `yield` returns a generator and generators evaluate lazily. Is there a difference between the above two?

Comment: `yr_result` just stores the generator object, so there's no difference between storing in a variable first or using the value directly like with other iterables.

Comment: `yield_range(10)` is assigned to `yr_result ` so they are the same thing.